# What makes a Question worthy of "Protection"?

Tags: discussion, question-protection

I'm merely asking out of curiosity, but what decides whether a question gets protected or not? Is it votes? Content? (Though that could be argued - by extension; votes) or is it a Mod choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the [recent changes to protection](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), a question can be protected *automatically* if it fulfills any of these criteria:

> 1. 3 answers from new users deleted – this handles questions that tend to attract large amounts of spam over time.
> 2. 5<sup>*</sup> answers from new users scoring <= 0 posted in the past 24 hours - this handles questions that are somewhat topical, and are attracting large numbers of "participants" who aren't actually contributing anything useful.
>
> <sup>*</sup>This value can be higher or lower on sites that have demonstrated “special” patterns of new-user interaction.

(I don't know what the value for Arqade is, but I'll assume it's 5 just as well.)

On top of that, any user with the [protect-questions privilege](/help/privileges/protect-questions) can protect a question manually, if the question is more than a day old.

A [guide on what should be protected](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/#guidelines) is also provided by the blog post:

> - **Do** protect questions that are attracting a lot of non-answers or very poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users.
> - **Don’t** protect questions just because they’re linked to on a high-traffic news site like Reddit or Ars Technica. While there’s certainly some correlation between sudden spikes in popularity and associated non-answers, not all popular questions suffer from this.
> - **Do** unprotect questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.

Answer (score 0):

Too many deleted answers will trigger it automatically. Alternately, a mod or a user with 15,000 rep can do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

Protection can be given automatically, if enough low-rep users give deleted answers, or by a mod or 15k user who has the [privilege to protect a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).